# How to update a field in a document in my monogoose model with Model.updateOne and $inc

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm making a digital currency app (for a closed community) and after making a transaction, I want to update the balance of the receiver in mongodb.

```
const create = (req, res) => {
    let transaction = new Transaction();
    transaction.sender = req.body.sender;
    transaction.receiver = req.body.receiver;
    transaction.amount = req.body.amount;
    transaction.save((err, doc) => {
        if(!err) {
            console.log(transaction.receiver);
            User.updateOne({username: transaction.receiver}, {$inc: {balance: 1}});

            res.json({
                "status": "success",
                "data": {
                    "transaction": doc
                }
            });
        } else {
            res.json({
                "status": "error",
                "message": "Could not make the transaction"
            });
        }
    })
}
```

When I test :

```
db.getCollection('users').updateOne({username: "aidenn"}, {$inc: {balance: 1}})
```

in RoboT3, the document updates. Why doesn't it work in my controller?

I test in Postman with:

```
{
    "sender": "Nicolas",
    "receiver": "aidenn",
    "amount": 1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work: saveOne return a promise to you:

```
const create = (req, res) => {
  let transaction = new Transaction();
  transaction.sender = req.body.sender;
  transaction.receiver = req.body.receiver;
  transaction.amount = req.body.amount;
  transaction.save(async (err, doc) => {
    if(!err) {
        console.log(transaction.receiver);
        const updated = await User.updateOne({username: transaction.receiver}, {$inc: {balance: 1}});
       //verify the log
        console.log({updated})

        res.json({
            "status": "success",
            "data": {
                "transaction": doc
            }
        });
    } else {
        res.json({
            "status": "error",
            "message": "Could not make the transaction"
        });
    }
})
```

Here a readeable code this could be better using repository pattern and service:

```
const create = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let transaction = new Transaction();
    transaction.sender = req.body.sender;
    transaction.receiver = req.body.receiver;
    transaction.amount = req.body.amount;
    const transactionSaved = await transaction.save();
    const updated = await User.updateOne(
      { username: transaction.receiver },
      { $inc: { balance: 1 } },
    );
    res.json({
      status: 'success',
      data: {
        transaction: transactionSaved,
      },
    });
  } catch (e) {
    res.json({
      status: 'error',
      message: 'Could not make the transaction',
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Hi, it did work, thank you so much!

Why does it need an async await (promise if I'm right)?
I'm quite new to javascript.

Comment: @nicolasvdsp The promise `async/await` will help you to wait for a transaction that mongoose does, that it has happened before you added it, you are telling mongoose to do an action but never wait for confirmation of the transaction, and then as you never wait you kill the process responded to the client